# Show images from my cloudinary library in pug template

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pug

I get an error when I display the images in timeline which it comes from my cloudinary on the format "https://res.cloudinary.........."

That does not display using this code

timeline.pug

```
each post in posts
  .main-card.col-md-6.col-lg-4
    .right-content
      .card-container
        .card.left-card
          .product-img
            img.c-image(src= `${post.imageCover}` alt=`${post.name}`)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What value does `post.imageCover` output?